# Python Fitting Linear Regression using Greedy Feature Selection

Tags: python, linear-regression, feature-selection

I'm trying to fit a linear regression model using a greedy feature selection algorithm. To be a bit more specific, I have four sets of data:

`X_dev`, `y_dev`, `X_test`, `y_test`, the first two being the features and labels for the training set and the latter two for the test set. The size of the matrices are `(900, 126)`, `(900, )`, `(100, 126)`, and `(100, )`, respectively.

What I mean by "greedy feature selection" is that I would first fit 126 models using one feature each from the `X_dev` set, choose the best one, then run models using the first one and each of the remaining 125 models. The selection continues until I have obtained 100 of the features that perform best among the original 126.

The problem I'm facing is regarding implementation in Python. The code that I have is for fitting a single feature first:

```
lin_reg.fit(X_dev[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1), y_dev)
lin_pred = lin_reg.predict(X_test)
```

Because the dimensions don't match (`(100, 126)` and `(1, )`) I'm getting a dimension mismatch error.

How should I fix this? I'm trying to predict how the model performs when using the single feature.

Thank you.

Comment: Post the rest of your code

Comment: Also, there is undoubtedly an implementation of this already built for you in scikit or some other library. Find it and save yourself the hassle

Comment: Unfortunately, this is basically the entire code that I have atm. The rest are the usual `import` statements for NumPy and sklearn with the `np.load` statements for the data. I'll take your advice though and look for an implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the same transformation to X_test

```
lin_reg.fit(X_dev[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1), y_dev)
lin_pred = lin_reg.predict(X_test[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1))
```

I also don’t think the reshape is necessary.

```
lin_reg.fit(X_dev[:, 0], y_dev)
lin_pred = lin_reg.predict(X_test[:, 0])
```

Should work as well

Comment: Thanks @John H your suggestion helped me solve it. The second method you proposed is the one I initially tried, but got the error message `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead.`